# Spark UDAF - using custom object type as bufferSchema

Tags: apache-spark

I created a class derived from UDAF，with my own type as bufferSchema. It compiles and submitted, unfortunately a CompileException is thrown when running it. Inside the log, the following line is found in the generated code:

`arrayWriter1.write(index1, element1);`

This element1 is of my own class, which of course spark doesn't have a method with this signature.

The following is my code:

```
class AggregateLinkResponse extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
// the input fields definition
::Nil
  )

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("xxx", MapType(IntegerType, ObjectType(classOf[MyOwnClass])))::Nil
  )

  override def dataType: DataType = StringType

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = Map[Int, MyOwnClass]()
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val responses : Map[Int, MyOwnClass] = buffer.getAs[Map[Int, MyOwnClass]](0)
// Get the input field values
// The logic to merge to buffer
    buffer(0) = responses
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    val response1 : Map[Int, MyOwnClass] = buffer1.getAs[Map[Int, MyOwnClass]](0)
    val response2 : Map[Int, MyOwnClass] = buffer2.getAs[Map[Int, MyOwnClass]](0)

// the logic to merge

    buffer1(0) = response1
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    new Gson().toJson(buffer.getAs[Map[Int, MyOwnClass]](0))
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. If it is possible to use my own class in bufferSchema，how to do it?
2. If it is not allowed, I know two options:

   a. I can serialize the buffer object into bytes or json，then deserialize it every time.

   b. Define a complicated bufferSchema using the predefined Spark types, including several ArrayTypes.

Which option has better performance, a or b? The the length of the arrays in the middle object changes and get longer and longer. I heard from people that ArrayType is copied each time. Is the performance penalty big?

Comment: I have the same problem.. did you manage to solve this issue somehow?